# Writing an example of two functions. Easy question.

Tags: functions, solution-verification

I'm asked to write an example of two functions $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f \neq g$ and $f \circ g = g \circ  f$.

Is this just as simple as having $f(x)=x+1$ and $g(x)=x+2$. Sorry if this is simple I just want to make sure I am correct as I am having a major mind block!

Comment: Yes, you're correct.

Comment: Also, any $g = f^{-1}$, if such exists and $f (x) \neq x$.

Comment: What do you mean by $f = / = g$?

Comment: @BIS HD: That $f$ does not equal $g$.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is okay. Alternative:

For $f$ take the identity. Then for $g$ you can take any function except the identity.